# get auth code from URL response - Python

Tags: python, http, url, post, python-requests

I'm using [OneDrive Python SKD](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) in order to handle authentication with OneDrive SDK. The authentication is done as:

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer

redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/"
client_secret = "your_app_secret"

client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(client_id='your_client_id',
                                        scopes=['wl.signin',
                                                'wl.offline_access',
                                                'onedrive.readwrite'])

auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)

#this will block until we have the code
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)

client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)
```

However since I use a EC2 instance to run this authentication, and furthermore I don't want to utilize a browser just for that, the code blocks indefinitely. Here's the `get_auth_code` from Microsoft:

```
def get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri):
    """Easy way to get the auth code. Wraps up all the threading
    and stuff. Does block main thread.
    Args:
        auth_url (str): URL of auth server
        redirect_uri (str): Redirect URI, as set for the app. Should be 
            something like "http://localhost:8080" for this to work.
    Returns: 
        str: A string representing the auth code, sent back by the server
    """
    HOST, PORT = urlparse(redirect_uri).netloc.split(':')
    PORT = int(PORT)
    # Set up HTTP server and thread
    code_acquired = threading.Event()
    s = GetAuthCodeServer((HOST, PORT), code_acquired, GetAuthCodeRequestHandler)    
    th = threading.Thread(target=s.serve_forever)
    th.start()
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)
    # At this point the browser will open and the code
    # will be extracted by the server
    code_acquired.wait()  # First wait for the response from the auth server
    code = s.auth_code
    s.shutdown()
    th.join()
    return code
```

I want to return the code. Here's a sample of `auth_url`:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?scope=wl.offline_access+onedrive.readwrite&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id='your_client_id'
```

When I enter that URL in the browser, I get the code back:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=Mb0bba7d1-adbc-9c1d-f790-3709cd0b9f16
```

SO I want to avoid that cumbersome process to get the code back by using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was struggling with the same problem - I wanted to get the code using requests library. I managed to do it somehow, but I'm doubting that this isn't a very sustainable solution. Hopefully, after reading my solution you will understand better how the authentication works and you might find an improved solution.

I have a Python Flask app with mySQL database. Occasionally, I want to create a backup of the database and send the backup file to my OneDrive, plus I want to fire this process inside my Flask App.

First, I registered my App at [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) and added a new platform *Web* with redirect url http://localhost:8080/signin-microsoft. I gave the app read and write permissions and stored the Application Id (`client_id`) and Application Secret (`client_secret`).

Second, I added a new route to my Flask App. Note that my Flask App is running on localhost:8080.

```
@app.route("/signin-microsoft", methods=['GET'])
def get_code():
    return 'Yadda'
```

Third, I replicated the HTTP request header created by my browser to my `requests.get` call. That is, I opened Chrome, pasted `auth_url` to address bar, hit enter, inspected the request header and copied its content to my code.

```
r = requests.get(auth_url, 
headers = {"Host" : "login.live.com",
           "Connection" : "keep-alive",
           "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
           "Accept-Language" : "fi-FI,fi;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
           "User-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
           "Cookie": (SUPER LONG WONT PASTE HERE)})
```

Fourth, I parsed the code from url the request was redirected.

```
re_url = r.url
code = re_url.split('code=')[-1]
```

Here is the final code:

```
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/signin-microsoft'
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
client_id = CLIENT_ID
api_base_url='https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/'
scopes=['wl.signin', 'wl.offline_access', 'onedrive.readwrite']

http_provider = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth_provider = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(
http_provider = http_provider, client_id=client_id, scopes=scopes)

client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(api_base_url, auth_provider, http_provider)
auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
r = requests.get(auth_url, 
    headers = {"Host" : "login.live.com",
               "Connection" : "keep-alive",
               "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
               "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
               "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
               "Accept-Language" : "fi-FI,fi;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
               "User-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
               "Cookie": (SUPER LOOONG)})
re_url = r.url
code = re_url.split('code=')[-1]
client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)
```

I think that there are two main points here: You need a HTTP server that listens redirect uri (in Microsoft's example they used HTTPServer from `http.server`) and you need to get the headers of the request right. Without the headers, the request won't redirect correctly and you won't get the code!